# What does “Something has to go” mean

Tags: sentence-meaning, british-english, sentence-usage

Hello to all community members.
I am preparing for the IELTS listening and rehearsing the cambridge books IELTS listening tests. I marked one question wrong and when i checked the typescript and checked the correct answer but I'm unable to understand the meaning of the sentence which shows the clue for the correct option. The sentence is

> I also joined the debating society, It's fun, but with all rehearsing
>   I'm doing,  Something has to go, I'm afraid that's the one.

So here I didn't get the correct meaning of this sentence and particularly the last of the sentence.
Any help would be appreciated to grasp the meaning of this sentence.

Comment: I know these tests are often poorly phrased, but I can't believe that's an exact copy of how the sentence was punctuated. Are you certain that's how it actually appeared?

Answer (score 2):

In this context, it means "I have to give up one of my activities."

Answer (score 0):

"Something has to go" is an idiom meaning that, out of a number of items, one of them has to be eliminated.

"We had 12 football players -- one of them had to go."

"We have too many pets and children. One of them has to go."

"I've got too many beanie babies. Some of them have to go."