# Is it clear and natural to say "rehearse the IELTS test"?

Tags: word-usage

This series of books contains some IELTS tests.

[image]

[An ell post](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/212009/117396) uses the phrase "rehearse the IELTS test" to refer to practice with tests in those books.

Is it clear and natural to use "rehearse" that way?

[From Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/rehearse?q=rehearsing)

> The musicians rehearsed (the symphony) for the concert.

In accordance with the usage from the example, should I say it like this?

> Doing exercise to **rehearse for** the IELTS test.

Answer (score -1):

In the US, we would say "I am doing the exercise to practice for the IELTS test." We use "rehearsal" for performance-oriented things, and for larger (more people and/or more involved than one person sitting taking a test) things. We rehearse music and theater performances, we practice tests and batting skills. And standardized tests. As a side issue, "Doing exercise" sounds unnatural -- we would put an article in front of the exercise - "Doing an exercise", "Doing this exercise", etc. This assumes that "exercise" is one part of the practice exam; if that isn't the case, I don't know what "Doing exercise" is trying to say.

Comment: You can also use the plural, "Doing exercises," especially if you're working through more than one exercise (or even just answering more than one question) in one session.